# mysql manipulation using php - entry-attribute-value model .. help

Tags: php, mysql

Hy to all ... 
I have the following mysql structure (online shop) where submenu@2 represents subcategory for that product... tabel submenu id 2 ... So i store the attributes row by row for a certain product category based by groups :

```
attribute`s table :
(id, subcategory_id, group, name, link, location)
(1, submenu@2, display, Size, 0, 0)
(2, submenu@2, display, Colors, 0, 0)
(3, submenu@2, display, Display type, 0, 0)
(4, submenu@2, display, Contrast, 0, 0)
(5, submenu@2, conectivity, VGA, 0, 0)
(6, submenu@2, conectivity, HDMI, 0, 0)
(7, submenu@2, conectivity, DSUB, 0, 0)
```

What i want is to show this (admin panel) in a single table row (`<tr><td></td></tr>`) like this :

```
<tr>
<td>submenu@2</td>  
<td>display</td>
<td>Size - Colors - Display Type - Contrast</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>submenu@2</td>
<td>conectivity</td>
<td>VGA - HDMI - DSUB</td>
</tr>
```

The table rows are separated by groups for the same product. 
I'm trying for 3 hours to think how to accomplish this and i have no clue ... Maybe a different mysql query will do the trick (now i'm making a `select * from table_name` and thought using php `if` will do it... but no success )

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysql's group concat function ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat )

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name, " - ") FROM attributes GROUP BY group
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: I thought using that `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ' - ') FROM attributes GROUP BY group;` but .. I want to add a link to the names containing the ID so i can remove them if clicked ...

Comment: Then I would advise you to write a postprocessing function and not some ungodly query :)

Comment: That is what i don't know how to do ? Do you have any ideea ?

Comment: I've tried but i don't know how to manipulate `<tr><td>` .. and why can't I concatenate `id (primary key)` ? When doing `GROUP_CONCAT(id)` the mysql returns `BLOB[5 oct]` instead of `1,2,3,4` ? why ?